# Categorical model

Tags: regression, categorical-data

Suppose you have a table:

```
   Smoking
Death  Low Moderate High
  Yes    50  100  150  
  No     4   10   14
```

I know a chi square test is best an determining the independence of variables but how do you create a model for this data where Death is the response variable.

Answer (score 2):

See [logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression). 'Death' as the response variable, 'Smoking' as a predictor - either nominal or score the levels as seem appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, your "No" line has 4 values while your "Yes" line has only 3.  Some sort of typo, but it's not obvious what. Also, what about people who don't smoke at all?

Second, @Scortchi 's suggestion of logistic regression is a good one; but don't you want to have some covariates? Age etc.?

Finally, depending on what data you've got, survival analysis might be called for.

Comment: I only have these two variables but I am unsure how to run a logistic regression using this data. Low includes people who don't smoke. Also what variables do I need for survival analysis?

Comment: How to model it depends on what software you have.  For survival analysis you would need time to death. Is this homework of some kind? If so, it should have the self-study tag; if not, then it's hard to see the point of doing this with such limited data

Comment: I was assuming the data was made up as an illustration.  We all die, smokers & non-smokers alike.  Real studies on smoking & disease have dozens of covariates at least. [Survival analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis) is used when you're measuring time till death or till the end of the study. If for some reason you were conducting an experiment where you made rats smoke 100's of cigarettes a day & that's all the data you recorded over its course, logistic regression is still your best bet.

Comment: In any case, could you explain what aspect of logistic regression you're unsure about?

Comment: Just how to run it in R. I am not sure how to set it up. I understand you are modelling the log of the odds ratio vs. predictor but I can't  build the model in R

Comment: Look at `glm` with `family=binomial`